# Can pointers to child objects be treated like pointers to parent objects?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, binary-search-tree, nodes

I am working on building a binary search tree using interface-type classes that were given to me. I have a BSTInterface class which consists of pure virtual functions. It is being inherited from by BST.h which is being implemented by BST.cpp. The BSTInterface spesifices a function called getRootNode() which returns a NodeInterface* My NodeInterface.h is a class consisting of pure virtual functions which is inherited from by Node.h which is implemented by Node.cpp. In my BST::getRootNode() function can I return a Node*, or do I have to return a NodeInterface*? If I have to return a NodeInterface*, can I simply set a NodeInterface*=Node*? Any help understanding the relationship between parent and child objects would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can return a pointer to a derived class as a pointer to base class. That's the basis of polymorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Particular to your case, C++ allows for [covariant return types](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type). This means that you cannot only return a derived class type from an inherited method, but you can also declare the inherited function to return the devired type:

```
class Node {};
class SpecialNode : public Node {};

class Base {
public:
    virtual Node* getRootNode () = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    virtual SpecialNode* getRootNode () override { 
        /* return a special node... */ 
    }
};
```

In general, you can assign an pointer of the derived type to a pointer of the base type:

```
Node* node = new SpecialNode();
```

Note that this is only true for references and pointers. You cannot do the same with objects that are not declared as pointers or references:

```
void someFunction (Node node) {}

SpecialNode sn;

// Causes "slicing" to occur
someFunction(sn);
```

Slicing occurs when enough memory is allocated only for the base class, since the compiler uses the type information for the node parameter through its parameter declaration (the compiler allocates enough memory only for `Node`, not `SpecialNode`). If the following were declared

```
class Node {
private:
    int x;
};

class SpecialNode : public Node {
private:
    int y;
};
```

The "y" data member would not be present in the node passed to `someFunction`, since it has been "sliced." Note that this only occurs in pass by value parameters, not in pass by reference or pass by pointer. For more information, see [object slicing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Comment: Glad to help. As a side note, the references and pointers work because the size of a pointer (and a reference, usually implemented using a pointer by the compiler) are always the same size on the same machine. Therefore, a pointer to the base type is the same size as a pointer to the derived type. The same cannot be said for the base and derived object: The base object has a single integer (x), while the derived object has two integers (x and y). That is the underlying reason why pointers and references do not suffer from object slicing.